# How to export table to csv/excel with grouped columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, csv, object

I would like to know how to export json to csv which has group column headers.
I can generate the table, but how to export in csv format,
Any library or any way to do , please help

```
var obj =  {
  options: {
    w1: {start:"sep",end: "6"},
    w2: {start:"nov", end: "5"}
  },
  intervals: {
    t1: {begin: "1", end: "2", totalqty: 2,totalamt: 200},
    t2: {begin: "4", end: "7", totalqty: 3, totalamt: 300},
  }
  items: [
    {
      name: "s1",
      desc: "sample1",
      w1: {t1: {qty:0, amt: 100},t2: {qty:1, amt: 200}},
      w2: {t1: {qty:1, amt: 100},t2: {qty:2, amt: 200}}
    }
    {
      name: "s2",
      desc: "sample2",
      w1: {t1: {qty:0, amt: 100},t2: {qty:0, amt: 0}},
      w2: {t1: {qty:0, amt: 0},t2: {qty:1, amt: 200}}
    }
  ]
}
```

[Excepted Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAS9u.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export JSON to Excel, you can use this library:
https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

If you want to export JSON to CSV you can use PapaParse:
https://www.papaparse.com/

But you can't export grouped columns in CSV, you must somehow flatten them, for example you can replicate the columns name with the group name as prefix, like `Sep06-1to2`, `Sep06-4to7`, etc. or just create 1 CSV file per group